# External RAM through USB

Tags: usb, memory

Is it possible to mount RAM cards **externally** and connect them **through USB** to my computer? I assume it's possible, but I haven't seen such a RAM --> USB converter after hours of search. All my RAM slots are taken up, and I'd love to use two more which I have lying around.

Comment: The USB Interface would be much too slow to accommodate Memory. So I do not think this idea will work

Comment: If such device exists, it will cost more than a new CPU+mother board since the development cost of the USB-to-RAM chip is too high and need is too few. And it can only be used as RAM disk instead of true RAM.

Comment: @John - I was trying to get some hard numbers to prove DDR4 RAM is faster than 5Gbps USB 4.0 or Thunderbolt while answering this question.  Newer USB standards would be slower than DDR4 RAM but possibly faster than RAM in the past with old plan PCI 133Mhz busses and what not.

Comment: What do you mean under "RAM cards"? Do you mean "RAM modules? DIMMs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USB is a peripheral.  This means there's software and hardware layers between the CPU and a USB device.

> Hardware layers: CPU <-> PCIe bus <-> USB controller <-> USB device
>
> Software layers: Hardware <-> OS Kernel <-> USB bus driver <-> Device-specific device driver <-> Application

RAM works like this:

> [ CPU <-> CPU cache <-> MMU ] <-> RAM

and everything in brackets is actually part of the CPU so it's superfast.

But most importantly, RAM is *visible* to the CPU without having to talk to a controller.  It's just *there*.

Getting data in and out of a USB device always involves asking the controller to talk to a device and move packets of data.  USB works more like a network adapter than RAM.

So you can get a bunch of RAM, connect it to a USB controller, and have it work like a super fast storage device, but not RAM.

---

Some busses have DMA capability and can directly read and write RAM.  This includes PCIe.  PCIe is available on your motherboard's expansion slots, and it's also available via Thunderbolt, which is part of the new USB 4.0 standard.

Other DMA-capable busses include Firewire and PCMCIA.

Technically, you can read and write to the video RAM on PCIe video cards.  So it is possible.  I am unsure of the state of getting graphics cards working over Thunderbolt, this may or may not have happened yet.

As far as just plain RAM attached to PCIe or Thunderbolt, no one has done that yet.